# Modifying Raster Layer with Python Console

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-python-console

I am looking for a way to edit a raster file which has already been loaded into QGIS through the Python console (i.e. I would like to edit the raster through the console).  Specifically, I would like to be able to set transparency, scale and move the raster layer.  It seems like GDAL is the easiest way to do this, but I haven't had any success.  I can import raster layers just fine using the: `gis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("FILE PATH", "FILE NAME")` command, but can't get any further.

If this is something which is easier accomplished with a stand-alone Python script that is alright too.  In the end I want the ability to add multiple raster images from a defined location based on a text file which indicates their location, size etc.

Version 1.8, will be changing to 2.0.1 soon.